# Изменение путей импорта. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, импорт, package

У меня есть пакет взаимосвязанных классов (Один импортирует другой), они находятся по пути типа a.b.c, мне нужно их перенести в a.d.b.c, проблема в том, что Android Studio заменяет package, но не заменяет пути импорта, тоесть остается a.b.c.class, вручную это огромная работа перемещать импорты, можно ли это автоматизировать ?

Answer (score 1):

### В Android Studio вы можете сделать это:

Например, если вы хотите изменить `com.example.app` на   `my.awesome.game, то`:

На панели «Проект» щелкните значок маленькой шестерни ([image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Снимите флажок / Отменить `Compact Empty Middle Packages`выбор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь ваш каталог пакетов будет разбит на отдельные каталоги

Индивидуально выберите каждый каталог, который вы хотите переименовать, и:

- Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши
- Выбрать Refactor
- Нажмите на Rename
- В диалоговом окне «Всплывающее окно» нажмите Rename
  Package«Добавить», а не «Переименовать каталог»
- Введите новое имя и нажмите Refactor
- Нажмите Do Refactor внизу
- Подаждите минуту, чтобы Android Studio обновила все изменения
- *Примечание. При переименовании com в Android Studio он может дать
  предупреждение. В этом случае выберите « Переименовать все»*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Теперь откройте файл сборки `Gradle ( build.gradle`- обычно appили mobile). Обновите applicationId новое имя пакета и `Sync Gradle`, если оно еще не обновлено автоматически:
И да главное не когда не ставьте имя пакета `example`  оно не  принимается в play market-e
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не совсем то что нужно, оно и вправду без труда переименовывает названия, но дело в том, что мне нужно посередине пути вставить новую папку, и вот её оно игнорирует, оно не вставляет ее в путь
com.ex.app -> com.newdir.ex.app

Comment: Вот то что ты просишь здесь есть посмотри

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: @PashaDoncov, если надо посередине вставить - создайте промежуточный пакет в нужном месте и просто перетащите туда всё что нужно мышью - оно само всё правильно пропишет, включая все импорты